# renomeando arquivo com posix c

Tags: c, arquivo

tenho um arquivo chamado TempFile.txt
fiz o seguinte script em c para renomear
arquivo recebendo o nome do arquivo a ser renomeado e o novo nome,
mas ele esta retornando este erro:

Error renaming file: Bad address
        Output new name:

O script é este abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char *oldname;
 char *newname;

 printf("\n\tInput name file: ");
 scanf("%s", oldname);

 printf("\n\tOutput new name: ");
 scanf("%s", newname);

 if(rename(oldname, newname) == 0)
  puts("File successfully renamed");
 else
  perror("Error renaming file");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sempre que publicar uma pergunta ou resposta formate o código com `Ctrl-k` ou utilize o botão `{}` do editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu erro é por causa das variáveis de entrada.

```
char *oldname;
char *newname;
```

São ponteiros e não possuem um tamanho alocado neles, para reparar seu código declare as variáveis `oldname` e `newname` como vetores.

```
char oldname[64];
char newname[64];
```